# Returning rows when flag field occurs on same Day

Tags: sql, sql-server, flags, having

I have a flag field that returns either '0' or '1'. I want to return rows when both a '0' and a '1' occur on the same day. My sytax is off but you get what I mean.

```
select employee, date, flag, account,
from table1
where flag = 0 and 1 for date
```

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate by date and count the number of occurrences of each value:

```
select employee, date, account,
from table1
group by date, employee, account
having sum(case when flag = 0 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when flag = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

In your case, assuming the flag is a number that only takes on the values of `0` and `1`, you could simplify it to one of the following:

```
having count(distinct flag) = 2;

having min(flag) <> max(flag);

having sum(flag) > 0 and sum(1 - flag) > 0;
```

Comment: I was thinking along those lines too, but in my case the flag could be triggered multiple times a day. So on a per day basis I may have many rows with different 'accounts' that have 0s and 1s.

Comment: @user2800758 . . . That is what this query does (assuming that `date` is really a *date* with no time component).